# Egglpant stop the test case

Tags: eggplant

I have a question, about stop the test case in Eggplant. I'm using a Gherkin language to create a handlers where I run a script or create a code. I was trying use assert to stop test case, but it only stop a handler where is started. Is there a way to stop test with command?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe throwing an exception is what you need. This will terminate the script.

[Eggplant Documentation Error Handling](https://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-error-handling.htm)